# How to enable keyboard navigation using code?

Tags: java, android, navigation, keyboard, programming-languages

Let say for some reason I have gotten a code where the main activity will present a dialog to allow the user to confirm exit or just cancel, I would like to implement that the user can use the arrow key to move left and right or rotate back to the two buttons (<kbd>cancel</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd>), how do I do it in code?

I found many solutions using the XML method where the view will have the `android:nextFocusRight="@+id/button2`. But how could this be done programmatically?

I could not find the equivalent using Java code.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setNextFocusRightId(int)) is an equivalent method. Each view has it.
Your case:

```
view.setNextFocusRightId(R.id.button2);
```